# I can't apply an image texture to an object

Tags: image, textures, blender, shapes, uv-mapping

I have made the shape of Hello Kitty (I started from a cube, merged all the vertices at the center and then I add one by one the vertices with CTRL+RightMouseButton and then I used fill to obtain the face) but when I go to UVediting tab I see only one point. I don't know what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to unwrap your mesh using the `U` hotkey, and you'll likely want to learn about "pelt" mapping (aka UV unwrapping using seams)